# Problem using Font Awesome for a Custom text in a view

Tags: views, 8

I have a custom entity (contract) created in a custom module (amap) by a bunch of BaseFieldDefinition.

This is the corresponding form.

> [image: screenshot]

One of the fields is a file defined this way.

```
$fields['file1'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
  ->setLabel(t('Source file'))
  ->setDescription(t('Source file (may be modified)'))
  ->setSettings([
    'target_type' => 'file',
    'file_extensions' => 'doc docx odt pages',
    'file_directory' => 'contrats',
  ])
  ->setDefaultValue('')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => $weight,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'string_textfield',
    'weight' => $weight,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
```

I have a view about a custom entity that displays some fields in table mode.

> [image: screenshot]

The actions are defined using *Custom text*. For example, the first one is the following one.

> [image: screenshot]

I use Font Awesome Icons in these Custom texts, and I have a problem with this: If the field 'file1' doesn't exist (as in the second row), it displays exclamation-triangle icon with no link, which is OK; if 'file1' exists (as in the first row), it displays the download icon with a link to the file (which is OK) and the exclamation-triangle icon with no link (which shouldn't be there).

What is wrong?

By the way, if I replace Font Awesome icons by a simple character, it works as expected.

```
{% if file1__target_id %}
  A
{% else %}
  B
{% endif %}
```

> [image: screenshot]

This is the HTML markup of the part of the page related to the view output (header and two rows).

```
<div id="block-mayo-content" class="block block-system block-system-main-block">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="views-element-container contextual-region">
            <div class="contextual-region view view-amap-contracts view-id-amap_contracts view-display-id-page_1 js-view-dom-id-404c9a70ff66dba6ebf5ff803693aafc74ec9d93a006df3b4e5af9de3b1c1b30">
                <div data-contextual-id="entity.view.edit_form:view=amap_contracts:location=page&amp;name=amap_contracts&amp;display_id=page_1&amp;langcode=fr" data-contextual-token="P56DWcQ_TYjoKxCel2ETjrZhR1bCqk6wRud80xjPtno">
                </div>
                <div class="view-header">
                    <a href="/amap/contract/add?destination=amap/contracts" title="Ajouter un contrat"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a> 
                </div>
                <div class="view-content">
                    <table class="views-table views-view-table cols-7 sticky-enabled">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="views-align-left views-field views-field-type views-align-left" id="view-type-table-column" scope="col">Type</th>
                                <th class="views-align-left views-field views-field-name views-align-left" id="view-name-table-column" scope="col">Nom</th>
                                <th class="views-align-center views-field views-field-startdate views-align-center" id="view-startdate-table-column" scope="col">Date début</th>
                                <th class="views-align-center views-field views-field-enddate views-align-center" id="view-enddate-table-column" scope="col">Date fin</th>
                                <th class="views-align-left views-field views-field-referentid views-align-left" id="view-referentid-table-column" scope="col">Référent</th>
                                <th class="views-align-center views-field views-field-isvisible views-align-center" id="view-isvisible-table-column" scope="col">Visible</th>
                                <th class="views-align-left views-field views-field-nothing views-align-left" id="view-nothing-table-column" scope="col">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="odd">
                                <td headers="view-type-table-column" class="views-field views-field-type views-align-left"><a href="/amap/contract_type/1" hreflang="und">Fruits rouges</a> </td>
                                <td headers="view-name-table-column" class="views-field views-field-name views-align-left"><a href="/sites/default/files/contrats/Contrat-1-20190101.pdf" target="_blank">Contrat Fruits rouges 2019</a> </td>
                                <td headers="view-startdate-table-column" class="views-field views-field-startdate views-align-center">01/01/2019 </td>
                                <td headers="view-enddate-table-column" class="views-field views-field-enddate views-align-center">31/12/2019 </td>
                                <td headers="view-referentid-table-column" class="views-field views-field-referentid views-align-left"><a href="/association/person/11" hreflang="und">Falzon Eric</a> </td>
                                <td headers="view-isvisible-table-column" class="views-field views-field-isvisible views-align-center">Oui </td>
                                <td headers="view-nothing-table-column" class="views-field views-field-nothing views-align-left views-field-nothing-2 views-field-nothing-5 views-field-nothing-3 views-field-nothing-4 views-field-nothing-1"><a href="/amap/contract/1/edit?destination=amap/contracts"><i class="fas fa-edit" title="Éditer le contrat"></i></a> <a href="/amap/contract/1/delete?destination=amap/contracts"><i class="fas fa-trash" title="Supprimer le contrat"></i></a> <a href="/amap/contract/1/subscribe?destination=amap/contracts"><i class="fas fa-list-alt" title="Entrer les souscriptions"></i></a> <a href="/amap/contract/1/Fruits%20rouges/export?destination=amap/contracts"><i class="fas fa-file-csv" title="Exporter le contrat"></i></a> <a href="/sites/default/files/contrats/Contrat-1-20190101.docx" target="_blank"><a href=" /sites/default/files/contrats/Contrat-1-20190101.docx "><i class="fas fa-download" title="Télécharger l'original"></a> </a> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td headers="view-type-table-column" class="views-field views-field-type views-align-left"><a href="/amap/contract_type/1" hreflang="und">Fruits rouges</a> </td>
                                <td headers="view-name-table-column" class="views-field views-field-name views-align-left">Contrat Fruits rouges 2020 </td>
                                <td headers="view-startdate-table-column" class="views-field views-field-startdate views-align-center">01/01/2020 </td>
                                <td headers="view-enddate-table-column" class="views-field views-field-enddate views-align-center">31/12/2020 </td>
                                <td headers="view-referentid-table-column" class="views-field views-field-referentid views-align-left"><a href="/association/person/11" hreflang="und">Falzon Eric</a> </td>
                                <td headers="view-isvisible-table-column" class="views-field views-field-isvisible views-align-center">Oui </td>
                                <td headers="view-nothing-table-column" class="views-field views-field-nothing views-align-left views-field-nothing-2 views-field-nothing-5 views-field-nothing-3 views-field-nothing-4 views-field-nothing-1"><a href="/amap/contract/2/edit?destination=amap/contracts"><i class="fas fa-edit" title="Éditer le contrat"></i></a> <a href="/amap/contract/2/delete?destination=amap/contracts"><i class="fas fa-trash" title="Supprimer le contrat"></i></a> <a href="/amap/contract/2/subscribe?destination=amap/contracts"><i class="fas fa-list-alt" title="Entrer les souscriptions"></i></a> <a href="/amap/contract/2/Fruits%20rouges/export?destination=amap/contracts"><i class="fas fa-file-csv" title="Exporter le contrat"></i></a> <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle " title="Pas d'original à télécharger"> </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I use the view UI to define the problematic icon.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Posting the HTML code produced the good and faulty icons in your question could shed some light on the problem and we might be able to help you

Comment: I have added HTML to my question.

Comment: Just relevant code would be better actually if you can.  Also how are you instructing drupal to display those icons ? custom code ? configuration ? where ? are you using https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/fontawesome ? did you search the issue queue.

Comment: What would be "relevant code"? To display the icons, I use Views UI. See the screen capture of the problematic field that I attached to my question in [Edit2].

Comment: I meant that we don't need the whole html, only what is close to the PROBLEM but its fine. Take a look at Hudri's answer, he has a point see how/why this is happening.  Try to uncompicate things by doing `Rewrite results: Output this field as a custom link` on the a different `Custom field` before or after to see where the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

You have nested link tags `<a...><a...></a></a>` - this is invalid HTML. Most browsers try to fix this by breaking it into two links `<a...></a> <a...></a>`, which most likely causes two icons in your case.

Comment: I agree! My problem is that I don't know how Views UI makes it happen...

Comment: Most likley (Views single Field Settings) "Rewrite Settings" > "Output this field as a custom link" or (Views single Field Settings) Checkbox "Link to this entity" .... maybe a combination of those two?